# Clone and restore github project with downloaded zip file and revoke access to user

Tags: angularjs, node.js, git, heroku, git-clone

Please excuse my ignorance, I am new to github.
I have been working with a developer who has been a living nightmare. I would appreciate advice on how to acquire my code and entire project and clone it to a new repository where I can have a new developer continue with the project.

The current stack is Heroku,AngularJS,NodeJS,MongoLab. I have downloaded .zip copies of the repository - can I simply create a new account and upload the zip file? Is there anything I should be cautious about? How can I gain complete control of my project and files? How can I restrict access to the current developer?

Comment: First of all, if you own the original repo, delete it

Answer (score 0):

Hit the fork option, which will fork it to your private repo. Then delete the one with the other dev.

Or, you could simply hit create new repository, and then use Github desktop to upload those files you downloaded to a new repo. You can do that with the current account.

Alternatively, you could just kick the other person off your current repo. CHeck this link out for more info: https://help.github.com/articles/removing-a-collaborator-from-a-personal-repository/

> Please excuse my ignorance

Don't worry, everyone has to start somewhere.

Hope this helped!